# How do I write an efficient query with start/end date objects with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Given MyDATE and MyUSER parameters, how do I write this efficiently:

```
inner join user_file on HUF_Idx = 
            (select top 1 runner.HUF_Idx
            from user_file runner
            inner join product on runner.HUF_HPR_Idx = product.HPR_Idx
            where runner.HUF_Emp_Nb = MyUSER
                and runner.HUF_Start <= MyDATE
                and (runner.HUF_End >= MyDATE OR runner.HUF_End IS NULL)
            order by product.HPR_Priority
            )
```

I'm retrieving the file of "highest priority" (a low number means a high priority) for a user at the time of MyDATE.

This does the job fine but it is very slow (I think, because of top 1, order by, and using two times the "user_file" table).

I've been searching for a better way but with MAX(HPR_Priority), how do I retrieve the HUF_Idx I want? Since I cannot group by HUF_Idx (I only want the "highest priority" one).

Thanks a lot in advance for any advice, I'm sure I'm missing a way more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Very difficult to answer without your full query, but I would be included to move the logic, including `user_file`, inside a [`CROSS APPLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two suggestion first you can use `outer apply` as this

```
outer apply (select top 1 runner.HUF_Idx
            from user_file runner
            inner join product on runner.HUF_HPR_Idx = product.HPR_Idx
            where runner.HUF_Idx = masterTable.HUF_idx 
                and runner.HUF_Emp_Nb = MyUSER
                and runner.HUF_Start <= MyDATE
                and (runner.HUF_End >= MyDATE OR runner.HUF_End IS NULL)
            order by product.HPR_Priority
            )
```

Second is adding a non clustered index on `user_file` on `HUF_Idx,HUF_HPR_Idx,HUF_Emp_Nb,HUF_Start,HUF_End` also on `product` on `HPR_Idx` (if there is not any)

Comment: outer apply helps a little, thanks! The indexes are not taken into account in the execution plan, and I end up having 28% of my query used by the "top N sort". Am I missing something? Here is my first index:

`CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [testIndex] ON [dbo].[user_file]
(
 [HUF_Idx] ASC,
 [HUF_Emp_Nb] ASC,
 [HUF_Start] ASC,
 [HUF_End] ASC,
 [HUF_HPR_Idx] ASC
)`

Comment: @Night It is not recommended but for testing use query hint as `from user_file runner WITH (INDEX (testIndex))`